# javascript cross domain image load -> check if loading image succeed loading

Tags: javascript

I have to load image from another site (cross domain)

my question is , i may can check somehow if the image has successfully loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you would put this in a load event listener like so:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    alert(this.src + " loaded");
}
img.src="http://example.com/images/a.png";
```

Comment: is the new Image() necessary ? if it is -why? if it's not -why?

Comment: @MorSela Yes it is necessary.  You have to create a new image object, but nothing is loaded at this point.  Once you giver it a souce, it starts to load.  If you just assign the url, js assumes you just want a string and not an image.

Comment: Move the onload function above the setting of the src property - cached images may fire the onload instantly, before the onload event handler is set.

Comment: @Greg thank you for that information! I'll change it directly.

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript Check this out

http://www.sajithmr.me/javascript-check-an-image-is-loaded-or-not

I know the way aroung with **jQuery**.

```
$('#image1')
.load(function(){
    $('#result1').text('Image is loaded!'); 
})
.error(function(){
    $('#result1').text('Image is not loaded!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading the image in an html tag, you can use the `onerror` event. For example:

`<img src="https://otherdomain.com/img.jpg" onerror="handleImgError();" />`

If `handleImgError()` runs, then you know that the image didn't load properly.

Comment: if i don't i can't do something similar in clean js?

Comment: You can use the Image object mentioned in the answer by Joseph, and use `img.complete`, which returns a boolean - true if the browser has completed downloading the image. You can also use the `onerror()` method, which would be very similar to the HTML shown above.